# How to notice other threads to kill themselves when one of them finished a specify task?

Tags: java, multithreading

I created 10 threads to finish a same task, if one of them finish it earlier, I'd like to kill the other threads.
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: What's the point of having 10 threads doing the same thing?

Comment: if there is nothing else you want to do in the main thread after a thread finishes its task, you can just call `System.exit(0)` to exit the program

Comment: @shmosel it's a very common technique known as a [Thread Pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool)

Comment: @dgnuff Thread pools are used to execute distinct (though sometimes similar or related) tasks. It sounds like OP is trying to execute the same task on multiple threads simultaneously.

Comment: You could use Boolean flag (`volatile` or `AtomicBoolean`) each thread periodically check that flag. If value is set to true by one thread all others just finish their `run()` method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a clean way to do this in straight up Java.  As a simple suggestion, you could:

1. create a ThreadGroup instance
2. add your ten threads to the thread group
3. start all 10 threads
4. write the code inside each thread's run() method so that, when it completes the work it's responsible for, it calls interrupt() on the ThreadGroup instance.  This will result in an interrupt() call on all the threads in the group
5. write the code inside each thread's block of work (the loop inside run()?) so that it checks its status periodically.  When it sees the status is interrupted, it should quit cleanly.